# How would I programmatically send the same request to different methods in Dropwizard and Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

Right now, I have some endpoints in a resource. These endpoints access some data and return it:

```
@Path("/v1/event")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class EventResource {
  private final DataStore dataStore;

  // constructor stuff

  @Timed
  @GET
  @Path("/all/total")
  public String getAll(@Bind({Bind.Params.QUERY}) Params params) throws Exception {
    return dataStore.getEventTotals(params);
  }
}
```

We completely revamped how our data is stored so now I have a resource that accesses this new data store:

```
@Path("/v2/event")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class NewEventResource {
  private final NewDataStore newDataStore;

  // constructor stuff

  @Timed
  @GET
  @Path("/all/total")
  public MyDataPojo getAll(@Bind({Bind.Params.QUERY}) Params params) throws Exception {
    return newDataStore.getEventTotals(params);
  }
}
```

What I would like to do now is somehow have the `v1` endpoint use both these resources. Some object would decide which `getAll` method to use based on some parameters in the `Params` object that is passed in.

The reason is we have some customers that have data in the old data store, and other customers have data in the new data store. We also have a bunch of other projects that are using our endpoints. It's not feasible or realistic to go change all the other projects to use the `v2` endpoint instead of the `v1` endpoint.

A couple thoughts. I could do something like this:

```
@Path("/v1/event")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class EventResource {
  private final DataStore dataStore;
  private final NewDataStore newDataStore;

  // constructor stuff

  @Timed
  @GET
  @Path("/all/total")
  public String getAllEndpoint(@Bind({Bind.Params.QUERY}) Params params) throws Exception {
    if (customerInNewDataStore(params.getCustomer())) {
      return getEventTotalsNew(params);
    } else {
      return getEventTotalsOld(params);
    }
  }

  private MyDataPojo getEventTotalsNew(Params params) throws Exception {
    return newDataStore.getEventTotals(params);
  }

  private String getEventTotalsOld(Params params) throws Exception {
    return dataStore.getEventTotals(params);
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that `getEvenTotalsNew` and `getEventTotalsOld` return different types. How would I be able to merge this? Also, doing this would be sort of a pain to do for every endpoint as there are quite a few endpoints in our codebase.

I've been reading about filters and intercepters in Jersey: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html.

Would a `ContainerRequestFilter` be able to accomplish what I want to do? Would I be able to access my `Params params` object in the filter?

Any other better ways to do this? I'm open to all ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have what you are looking for. You can use a pre-matching filter to modify the request.

This is based on your example stating that you have a v1 and v2 API, both of which are equal (apart from the versioning). I am using a custom header for routing.

Consider these two resources:

```
@Path("v1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource1 {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public String get() {
        return "Hello v1";
    }
}

@Path("v2")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource2 {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public MyResultObj get() {

        MyResultObj o = new MyResultObj();
        o.name = "pandaa";
        o.message = "Hello V2";

        return o;
    }

    public static class MyResultObj {
        @JsonProperty
        String name;
        @JsonProperty
        String message;
    }
}
```

These are both equal with the exception for the version type in the context and the return type. Note, the return type does not matter in this case. What ends up in the response is a json string regardless. In your case, you could also do something like:

```
Response.ok(myResultObject).build();
```

At that point all of your return types would just be Response.

Anyhow, Version 1 prints something, and version 2 returns an object.

The pre-matching (important, otherwise you can not change the URI) filter will look like this:

```
@PreMatching
public class RoutingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String headerString = requestContext.getHeaderString("IS_V2");
        boolean v2 = headerString != null && headerString.equals("yes");
        URI absolutePath = requestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath();

        if(v2) {
            URI v2Redirect = URI.create(absolutePath.toString().replace("v1", "v2"));
            requestContext.setRequestUri(v2Redirect);
        }

    }

}
```

It simply evaluates the header and replaces the version in the URI. There is probably a better way to do this, but then again this is just an example of how to approach this.

Finally, the test:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/vpn$ curl "localhost:9085/api/v1/test" --header "IS_V2: yes"
{"name":"pandaa","message":"Hello V2"}

artur@pandaadb:~/dev/vpn$ curl "localhost:9085/api/v1/test" --header "IS_V2: no"
Hello v1
```

Note how both are doing a request for V1. The first request though gets rerouted internally to v2.

You can write a more generic version (since you might need to be backwards compatible e.g. v1 -> v2 and v2 -> v1) so that it doesn't matter if people call v1 or v2.

Finally - I am not at all sure if this is a good solution :) Personally I would probably write a delegate as seen in your example.

I hope that helps!

Edit: finally - you should be able to use your params object. However this may result in you consuming the requests's input stream. I believe this can only be done once, so you may need to set a new stream after reading it as well.

Artur